# Error Text popup under EditText

Tags: android

I tried a lot and did R&D, but couldn't manage to show own custom error drawable under EditText.

Here is my code:

```
String str = "Please enter a valid email address”;

// This line is used to give color to error text.
ForegroundColorSpan colorSpan = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.YELLOW);

// This line is used to give background color to error text.
BackgroundColorSpan backColorSpan = new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE);

// This s basically a StringBuilder that implements CharSequence interface. 
SpannableStringBuilder strBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(str);

strBuilder.setSpan(colorSpan, 0, str.length(), 0);
EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et);
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn);

// This line shows our own icon in place of default icon. 
setError(CharSequence, Drawable);

So, strBuilder in next line is an implementation of CharSequence.
et.setError(strBuilder, drawable);
```

Any Solution?

Comment: Can you post your code and an image of what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

You need to call setBound() method on drawable object.
You need to put this line:

```
drawable.setBounds(0,0,drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a TextInputLayout, it has this feature inbuilt.

Check this link out, it has exactly what you need:

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-login-screen-using-textinputlayout--cms-24168

For details check google devs

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html